# PHP Foreach cycle echoes wrong Bootstrap table structure

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to populate a Bootstrap table in order to have a table like this:

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyW77.png)

The final result should be that i can see which student will be present on that day.

Now I've tried to cycle the result of my database queries and put them inside the table tr and td but I'm missing how to do it properly...and the code looks very confusing...

If i do this way:

```
<?php
  if($usersMON) {

       foreach ($usersMON as $userlun){ ?>

          <tr>
              <td class="text-center maiuscolo"><?=$userlun['name']?></td>

    <?php
       }


  }  ?>
  

  
  <?php
  if($usersTUE) {

       foreach ($usersTUE as $usermar){ ?>

              <td class="text-center maiuscolo"><?=$usermar['name']?></td>

    <?php
       }


  } 
  ?>
  

  
  <?php
  
  if($usersWED) {

       foreach ($usersWED as $usermer){ ?>

              <td class="text-center maiuscolo"><?=$usermer['name']?></td>

    <?php
       }


  } 
    ?>
  

  
  <?php
  
  if($usersTHU) {

       foreach ($usersTHU as $usergio){ ?>

              <td class="text-center maiuscolo"><?=$usergio['name']?></td>

    <?php
       }


  } 
    ?>
  

  
  <?php
  
  if($usersFRI) {

       foreach ($usersFRI as $userven){ ?>

              <td class="text-center maiuscolo"><?=$userven['name']?></td>

    <?php
       }


  } 
    ?>
    
    
    </tr>
```

I obtain this:

[Table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zllnh.png)

Could you suggest me a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prerequisite is that the user quantity is the same.

You could put the `$usersMON` ~ `$usersFRI` into an array.

```
array_push($allUsers, $usersMON, usersTUE, usersWED, usersTHU, usersFRI);
```

Then, show each student's name

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < $userQuantity; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($allUsers as $users) { ?>
        <td><?=$users[$i];?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$users = [
    $usersTUE,
    $usersWED,
    $usersTHU,
    $usersFRI
];

$col_count = count($users);
$row_count = 0;
foreach ($users as $u) {
    $row_count = max($row_count, count($u));
}

echo "<table>";
for ($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($t=0; $t<$col_count; $t++) {
        $user = $users[$t][$i] ?? [];
        echo "<td class='text-center maiuscolo'>" . $user['name'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```